# Burninate the healthcare-industry tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The [healthcare-industry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-industry) tag is absolutely not related to programming, and anything programming question that's related to the healthcare industry doesn't need this tag. Can it be burninated?

Also, I don't need questions like this:

> ## How to weight loss with Red bean barley porridge diet
>
> A barley and lentil "swelling" role, is also very interesting. We do
>   not think that swelling is edema. Look at the people, 10 there are at
>   least 5 ~ 6 body fat, which is also called swollen, bloated body.
>
> ...
>
> The second kind of method is simpler, is now less common thermos
>   bottle home and wash clean, put barley and beans on the inside, and
>   pour boiling water into the bottle head, bored, so it every night, get
>   up in the morning is porridge, just right when breakfast.

Comment: ..Buuut, but , what about all the sick childrens!!! Something feels un-karma like about this. sigh

Comment: There are a few questions that will need additional tagging, and a few that need outright closing & deletion.

Comment: Maybe don't kill it yet... I'm almost done with my barleyswelling.js jQuery plugin and this tag sounds perfect.

Comment: @Adel OMG , someone used that tag just now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924419/united-states-has-2-day-diet-entered-a-new-treatment

Comment: All question gone. Please block tag!

Comment: Burninate tag...and all questions with that tag.

Comment: I accidentally left out the "tag" when reading this question title...

Comment: I don't know -- coding standards attached to the healthcare industry might be sufficiently distinct to require some common properties?

Comment: @Yakk: Developers of such software concern themselves with keywords around FDA guidance and ISO standards, not a "healthcare-industry" tag.